# Impact of overclocking Cpu on battery life

Tags: overclocking

I want to know if overclocking the cpu will reduce the battery life.I know overclocking drains battery but will it affect the device battery in harmful way?

Comment: Heat is the number 1 enemy of phone/tablet batteries. Overclocking will increase the temperature and the strain on the battery and degrade its life faster. How much I don't know as it depends on way too many variables. See this for more also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/what-are-the-risks-to-overclocking-my-cpu?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Overclocking shouldn't actually damage your battery but it will make it drain quicker and as a side effect of that have a shorter overall life. Overvolting (giving the CPU more volts) could however damage your battery (overvolting can be common practise when applying a generous overclock) but of course this all depends on what device you're on and what processor it has in, some  processors that are understood by devs better can be overclocked more safely.